# How can I copy data from one set of tables into another set of tables on a regular basis

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In a sql server 2008 database, I have a set of tables that I want to save the history of on a regular basis.  To do this I created another set of tables to store this history.  Basically, the database structure looks like this:

```
+---------------+                +---------------+
| TableA        |                | TableAHistory |
+---------------+                +---------------+
| Key           |<--+            | Key           |<----+
| DataA         |   |            | Date          |     |
|               |   |            | DataA         |     |
+---------------+   |            +---------------+     |
                    |                                  |
+---------------+   |            +-----------------+   |
| TableB        |   |            | TableBHistory   |   |
+---------------+   |            +-----------------+   |
| Key           |   |            | Key             |   |
| TableAKey     |---+            | TableAHistoryKey|---+
| DataB         |                | DataB           |
+---------------+                +-----------------+
```

With this structure, I'm having trouble creating a stored procedure that can copy the current data into the history tables.  I can easily create the insert statement that copies the data from TableA into TableAHistory, but copying TableB's data is causing me problems.  When copying data into TableBHistory, I don't see how I can find what the TableAHistoryKey should be.  Here is what the insert statements look like now:

```
INSERT      TableAHistory([Date], DataA)
SELECT      CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DAY(GETDATE()), GETDATE())),
            DataA
FROM        TableA

INSERT      TableBHistory([TableAHistoryKey], DataB)
SELECT      ??? AS TableAHistoryKey,
            DataB
FROM        TableB
```

The only thing I can think of is to add a field on the history tables to temporarily store the corresponding table's key.  I could then join TableA, TableAHistory and TableB in the second insert statement, getting me access to the correct TableAHistoryKey.  I would rather not do this, since this added column would only be used for copying the data.

Is there another (common) way to do this?

**Edit**: Just to add a little clarity, the `Key` in TableAHistory is generated and not the same as the `Key` in TableA.  The same goes for TableBHistory and TableB.

**Edit**: Currently, this history only needs to be saved on a monthly basis and we have a convention in place to store a "month/year" as a date on the first day of the month.  Hence the weird `CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DAY(GETDATE()), GETDATE()))`.  Probably not the best way to do this, but it works.

Comment: why would you not keep the keys permanently in the history table?  it seems like replacing them would lose the reference to which record's history they were tracking.  you wouldn't have to make it a primary key, but it seems like you'd want to have that information.

Comment: The keys are really unneeded information.  The records in TableA and TableB will update and get deleted regularly, so keeping the reference seems fairly pointless.  Ultimately the users want to see what their data looked like last month, the month previous, etc...  I could add the keys in the table, but I just want to know if there is another way to copy the data into the history tables without adding the keys in the history table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would have thought that for a history table you would need a date the data was copied. If this is the case then, instead of the (presumably generated) key for the two history tables, copy the original key, and then in the history tables use a compound primary key of key plus date.

Comment: There is a date column on the TableAHistory table.  As I said in my comment on the original question, the records in the non history tables will be updated/deleted, so having the original key on the history table for the purpose of a reference is useless.  But it would make it possible to copy the data.  I was wondering if there is another simple way to copy the data that doesn't involve storing the original key.

Answer (score 4):

I would have your archive tables use the same schema as prod, but introduce an archiveID as part of the PK in each of the tables, including tableBHistory.

Then it should be easy to restore rows from a particular archive set.

Comment: @beth - no, add a variable and set it before all the copies run obviously.

Comment: I should have been more clear.  I'm looking to give our users the ability to see what their data looked like a month ago, two months ago, etc, so the `Date` column is needed.  I don't see, though, how adding an archiveID would help me with my problem.  I must be misunderstanding your suggestion.  Are you saying to add an archiveID and have the `Key` in TableA be a copy of the `Key` in TableAHistory.  I wasn't orginally clear, but these `Keys` are currently generated and different.

Comment: you could have the one date value associated with an archive table with an archiveID PK.  It groups the rows for any particular archive set.  getdate() on each row will return different values across the set, because the operation isn't instantaneous

Comment: Ah, I see now.  For the sake of brevity, I just used getdate() when in fact I am using `CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(DAY, 1 - DAY(GETDATE()), GETDATE()))`.  We are only saving history on a monthly basis, so this should be consistent across the insert.  The idea of adding an archiveID is good, though, if at some point in time we want to save history on a more regular basis.  I'll edit my question to clear this up.